# Solidity compile Error: Expected primary expression

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;<br/>

    contract ERC165 {

         function interfaceID() constant returns (uint)
         {
            bytes4[] sigs = type(this).signatures;
            uint mask = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < sigs.length; i++)
            mask ^= uint(sigs[i]);
        return mask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`type(this)` isn't valid Solidity code. I can't really suggest a fix, because I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think is something under development. That code come from here https://gist.github.com/axic/5d42693fab09acfa2fdd977f38805833

there is an issue in github for that: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1447 seems to be a feature that we'll see on solc 0.5.1